# How to bind value to the submit buttons wthich are created dynamically?

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of buttons.I am giving their name dynamically on pop up and by using `ng-repeat` i am displaying buttons on the parent form.So how to bind the values to the buttons.

```
<p ng-repeat="submits in form.buttons track by $index">
    <input type="button" id="button_{{$index}}" ng-value="submits">
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code:

```
<p ng-repeat="submits in form.buttons track by $index">
   <input type="button" id="button_{{$index}}" ng-model="newObject['button_'+ $index]" ng-value="submits">
</p>
```

Comment: What ever i give the name for it ,its taking true as a value.

Comment: its giving zero.How can we make it zero...ithe value must be what i have given the text right

Comment: k wait a while please

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/3YIRcu9VJjsRA0eVRfGY?p=preview ...once analyse it please..the program is not working in the fiddle but once see the concept

Answer (score 0):

```
<p ng-repeat="submits in form.buttons track by $index">
   <input type="button" id="button_{{$index}}" ng-click="isButtonClicked($index)">
</p>
```

try this and create a function in your controller

> $scope.isButtonClicked = function(index){ ....
>
> }

this should work